# Google Places API on Android: No route to host

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I am using google places api in my application to show nearby food locations.

I'm using the following code:

```
public class Background extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        pfr = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        lctn = "location=" + latitude + "," + longitude;
        key = "&key=my key";
        type = "&types=" + pfr.getString("type", "food");
        radius = "&radius=" + pfr.getString("radius", "500");
        sensor = "&sensor=false";
        StringBuilder requesturl = new StringBuilder(googlegives);
        requesturl.append(lctn);
        requesturl.append(radius);
        requesturl.append(type);
        requesturl.append(key);
        requesturl.append(sensor);
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet req = new HttpGet(requesturl.toString());
        Log.d("create", "0");
        try {
            HttpResponse res = client.execute(req);
            HttpEntity jsonentity = res.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(jsonentity);
            JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray resarray = jsonobj.getJSONArray("results");
            if (resarray.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "nothing found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                int len = resarray.length();
                for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                    lon = resarray.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("geometry")
                            .getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lng");
                    lat = resarray.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("geometry")
                            .getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat");
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(latLng)
                            .title(
                                resarray.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("name")
                                        .toString())
                            .snippet(
                                resarray.getJSONObject(j)
                                        .getJSONObject("formatted_address")
                                        .toString()));
                }
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

getting latitude and longitude as global variable for getting the user's current location, on running this application on my phone following appear in log cat

```
03-03 16:52:37.859: W/System.err(4780): java.net.SocketException: No route to host
03-03 16:52:37.906: W/System.err(4780):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
03-03 16:52:37.906: W/System.err(4780):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:357)
03-03 16:52:37.906: W/System.err(4780):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:204)
03-03 16:52:37.914: W/System.err(4780):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
03-03 16:52:37.914: W/System.err(4780):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1002)
03-03 16:52:37.914: W/System.err(4780):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
03-03 16:52:37.914: W/System.err(4780):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
03-03 16:52:37.914: W/System.err(4780):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-03 16:52:37.914: W/System.err(4780):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-03 16:52:37.914: W/System.err(4780):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
03-03 16:52:37.914: W/System.err(4780):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-03 16:52:37.914: W/System.err(4780):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-03 16:52:37.921: W/System.err(4780):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-03 16:52:37.921: W/System.err(4780):     at com.abhishekbietcs.locomap.Mapme$Background.doInBackground(Mapme.java:258)
03-03 16:52:37.921: W/System.err(4780):     at com.abhishekbietcs.locomap.Mapme$Background.doInBackground(Mapme.java:1)
03-03 16:52:37.921: W/System.err(4780):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-03 16:52:37.921: W/System.err(4780):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
03-03 16:52:37.921: W/System.err(4780):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
03-03 16:52:37.921: W/System.err(4780):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
03-03 16:52:37.921: W/System.err(4780):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
03-03 16:52:37.921: W/System.err(4780):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Why is this exception being thrown? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Check if `requesturl.toString()` produces a valid URL String.

Comment: No **route** not *router* :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566698/no-route-to-host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.net.SocketException: No route to host.

This exception occur when there is no route to connect to host.

I found your problem here.

**key = "&key=my key";**

Replace this with

```
String APIKEY="AIzaSyDcLMS0IKQL3N76rO-aD2thfO46r96OCQI";
key = "&key=" + APIKEY;
```

and you have made wrong link.

Your link:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?jsonlocation=25.4509294,78.630043&radius=15000&types=food&key=key&sensor=false

Link must be like:

```
String url = https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=25.4509294,78.630043&radius=15000&types=food&key=AIzaSyDcLMS0IKQL3N76rO-aD2thfO46r96OCQI&sensor=false
```

To get JSON you can use my code.

```
String data = getUrlContents(url); //Calling method
```

Definition of Method.

```
private String getUrlContents(String Url) 
{
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(Url);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()), 8);
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            content.append(line + "\n");
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content.toString();
}
```

Comment: the googlegives string is "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?json" and i m appending it using string builder, for getting the json object,i can'y figure out where to change??

Comment: @ lukas knuth, yes,it is returning a json,i checked in browser

Comment: @the individual requesturl.toString(); Give the value of this.

Comment: it is https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?jsonlocation=25.4509294,78.630043&radius=15000&types=food&key=key&sensor=false

Comment: @theindividual link should be link this.https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=28.632808,77.218276&radius=500&types=atm&sensor=false&key=APIKEY and I found problem in your link https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?json

Comment: @theindividual Link i made for you its https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=25.4509294,78.630043&radius=15000&types=food&key=AIzaSyDcLMS0IKQL3N76rO-aD2thfO46r96OCQI&sensor=false

Comment: i have changed string according to you the string is now  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=25.4604764,78.6431788&radius=15000&types=food&sensor=false&key=key
but the error remains, pulling my hair, please help

Comment: @theindividual you again commit mistake at the end of this link &key=key instead of this use like this &key=AIzaSyDcLMS0IKQL3N76rO-aD2thfO46r96OCQI

Comment: yup i have done very silly mistakes in url,but this sir i have edited key insted of writing the whole key...kind of privacy of my key but it is disclosed at seems by mistake, this time i have put Log.d("create", requesturl.toString()); to get the url and assuring you it is working in browser

Comment: @theindividual So now problem has solved or not? If no route problem has solved accept this answer.

Comment: but its working in browser your link problem has solved and now other problem let me look.

Comment: @theindividual Now check my edited answer and now this i am expecting url is correct and have internet in device and debug the application and check the response. its should be JSON string.

Comment: it is not completing the HttpResponse res = client.execute(req); statement so what to do with json, i am not getting the json to parse it

Comment: @theindividual Use my above code Its will give JSON string as response. I used this function in my app its working fine.

Comment: yup getting the json string, but have to change the logic as u knw i m looking for the latitude and longitude of food to add markers on map

Comment: @theindividual Now your earlier problem of no route and this JSON string problem has been solved. As we can not discuss here more. Now whatever your requirement you can do and search on google and accept this answer if its useful for you.